# In Doctor Who's The Time of the Doctor, how is sound heard in outer space?

Tags: doctor-who, space

The premise of the episode is that hundreds of different spaceships from different alien species are brought to one place (Trenzalore, attracted to there from an unknown message sent throughout the galaxies in a sound pulse... but how can they hear the message, if sound cannot travel in space?

Comment: Did the episode use the phrase "sound pulse"?

Comment: By coincidence, I saw that episode a couple of days ago, and don't remember any mention of a _sound pulse_.  Please point to where it is stated to be a ... Gah! ... sonic transmission.

Answer (score 4):

The message is not described as a sound; it's described as "projected through all of time and space on a repeating cycle" and "received throughout the universe."  The message is represented as a sound in some places, but that's just to let the viewers (us) know there's a message; it's not a literal representation of the message.

The lead in voice-over [to that episode](http://www.planetclaire.org/quotes/doctorwho/christmas-specials/the-time-of-the-doctor/) states:

> This planet sent the universe a message. A bell, tolling among the
>   stars, ringing out to all the dark corners of creation. And everybody
>   came to see. Although no one understood the message, everyone who
>   heard it found themselves afraid.

Now, during that voice-over, there's a [sound used to represent the message](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3yJXcoIheficVI2c3Q2RXJRdW8/view?usp=sharing).  It's playing during an orbital shot, so it's clearly not actual sound, just a way of telling the viewer "there's a message going out."

The message is untranslatable through the usual means:

> **Handles**: The message was received throughout the universe.
>
> **The Doctor**: Yes yes. The message. The message. Even I can't translate
>   it. I mean why is everyone here if they don't understand it?

Later, this exchange describes the message:

> **Tasha Lem**: That message is transmitting through all of space and time.
>   What did it make you feel?
>
> **The Doctor**: Feel?
>
> **Tasha Lem**: Every sentient being in the universe who detected that
>   signal felt something. Something overpowering.
>
> **The Doctor**: What?
>
> **Tasha Lem**: Fear. Pure, unadulterated dread.

So, it transmits through space and time and causes an emotional reaction when "detected" (as opposed to "heard").  It's clearly not sound, and it works in a very timey-wimey spacey-wacey way.  Let's call it electricwimetic with atypical propogation characteristics.

Comment: +1 for `electricwimetic`. I haven't the foggiest what that means, but I like it!

Answer (score 3):

A transcript of Time of the Doctor can be found on chakoteya.net [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-16.html), if you do control-F (or command-F on a Mac) to search for the word "sound", that word doesn't appear anywhere in the episode, so I think you are misremembering something. The Doctor has a cyberman's head he calls "Handles" with him in the TARDIS, and Handles just tells him "The message was received throughout the universe" and "It is being projected through all of time and space on a repeating cycle" but doesn't say specifically how it was broadcast. The message was originally coded and unintelligible, but when the Doctor learns it's a Gallifreyan message he gives Handles the "Seal of the High Council of Gallifrey" which has "an algorithm imprinted in the atomic structure" that allows Handles to translate it, and Handles says "Warning. **Translation will be available to all lifeforms in range.** Translation follows. Doctor who? (slightly different voice each time.) Doctor who? Doctor who? Doctor who? Doctor who? Doctor who? Doctor who?" Only after that do other races like the Daleks and Cybermen understand it.

Comment: Oh okay! I must have interpenetrated what I was watching. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In regards to he hearing of sounds in space, we still have a problem despite the fact that the message from Trenzalore could be/probably is a radio type wave instead of a sound wave. What about the horn blow of the papal mainframe ship and the voice of Tasha Lem projected through the vacuum?!?!?!?  There is no medium to transmit these vibrations from ship to ship.

Now, in my opinion, these can be heard due to the Tardis' (and maybe all spaceships') ability to pick up signals/sounds from one atmosphere pocket (around the papal mainframe) and translate them within the atmospheric shell held around the Tardis.  For example, the horn blast heard from the ship would not be heard unless some type of signal was sent from the papal ship to the intended recipient.  The Tardis then picked up this signal and translated this as sound vibrations in the appropriate parts of the atmospheric shell.  the same must be true about the voice of Tasha Lem.  Anyways...

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Do you have any evidence which would support this theory?